# Atom platformio won't run python

Tags: command-line, atom-editor, platformio

I am having trouble getting my atom set up as an IDE.  The platformio-ide-terminal package wont run python.  I have a simple file called myfile.py which prints a sentence.  My working directory is in documents in a fodder I've created for a course I'm using atom for.I get the following error message in my command line in atom:

```
PS C:\Users\Angus\Documents\UdemyPython_10Apps\Beyond_Basics> python3 myfile.pypython3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, oroperable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

At line:1 char:1
+ python3 myfile.py3
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: what do you get if you type: 'which python3' ?

Comment: why are you running python in the terminal? Why not just execute it from editor window.

Comment: I just ran a test in Atom.  I opened a sample python file. From the editor window I ran my code and it worked fine. I then opened a terminal window by selecting the platformio-idt-terminal package.  This opened the terminal window right below editor window.  In this terminal window i typed:  python myfile.py  The file again executed to completion.

Comment: Hi this is super embarrassing.  I couldn't get my windows command prompt to run it either.  Turns out the pc wouldn't call python with "python3" instead I had to use "py -3".

Comment: Not embarrassing!  just confusion on the proper alias.  Glad you fixed it!

Comment: You might want to answer your own question,  accept your answer and get the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some windows terminals accept py -3 instead of python3 as the proper alias, the command to open and run python programs.